# Трансформация содержимого внутри контейнера

Tags: html, css

Проблема состоит в том что при использовании свойства `transform` родительский элемент игнорирует увеличение размера дочернего элемента.

**Пример 1: Дочерний контейнер с использованием width и height**

```css
.main {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.element {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

**Пример 2: Дочерний контейнер с использованием transform**

```css
.main {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.element {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: scale(1, 2);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы `transform` учитывал родительский контейнер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В спецификация [CSS Transforms Module Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/) написано следующее:

> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, the
>   transform property does not affect the flow of the content surrounding
>   the transformed element

---

> Для элементов чей макет регулируется коробочной моделью CSS, свойство
>   трансформации не воздействует на поток окружающего контента
>   трансформированного элемента

P.S Для того чтобы растянуть родительский контейнер придется воспользоваться средствами js.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что при трансформации не происходит **увеличения** элемента - происходит лишь его визуальное изменение. Если мы с помощью js запросим размеры трансформированного элемента, окажется, что они остались неизменны:

```js
let elem = document.getElementsByClassName('element')[0];
let styles = getComputedStyle(elem);
console.log('ширина: '+styles.width);
console.log('высота: '+styles.height);
```

```css
.main {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 50px;
}

.element {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: scale(1, 2);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Поэтому если необходимо, чтобы родитель реагировал на изменение дочернего элемента, надо либо изменять сами размеры, либо родителя тоже трансформировать одновременно с "дочкой".

Comment: Да, я сам это заметил что на DOM свойство transform никак не влияет. Однако если через консоль отладки в режиме выделения элемента навести на трансформированный блок, то высота будет 200px. Есть ли способ отловить эту высоту/ширину (кроме написания специального кода на js который будет просматривать transform свойство)?

Comment: @MaximPro, да нет - в режиме отладки высота тоже 100px: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhaeB.jpg